# Adding or editing data to an existing table entry in core data

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

I am trying to build an app that stores data about gym clients on a weekly basis using core data.  I have managed to get my save button to store all the clients data and then show the information when I click on the clients name that is used to populate a table.  I can delete the client but I can't add or amend existing data which is an important step.

I will attach my code and a screenshot of the app to show what I am trying to achieve. This is my code I've written that should allow me to add to the client but I click on Week 1 button everything is 0.0 and weight is missing and when I return to the table it has created a new blank client.

ClientListViewController:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

var clientItems : [Client] = []

class ClientListViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {



    @available(iOS 2.0, *)
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return clientItems.count
    }

    @available(iOS 2.0, *)
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        let items = clientItems[indexPath.row]

        cell.textLabel?.text = items.name
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.disclosureIndicator

        return cell
    }

    func getData() {

        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

        do {
            clientItems = try context.fetch(Client.fetchRequest())
        } catch {
            print("Fetch Failed")
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

        if editingStyle == .delete {
            let item = clientItems[indexPath.row]
            context.delete(item)
            (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()

            do {
                clientItems = try context.fetch(Client.fetchRequest())
            } catch {
                print("Fetch Failed")
            }
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        getData()
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "segue" {

            let destinationVC = segue.destination as! ClientViewController
            let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
            let client = clientItems[(indexPath?.row)!]
            destinationVC.client = client

        }
    }
}
```

WeekStatsViewController:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class WeekStatsViewController: UIViewController {

    var client: Client? = nil
    var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext!

    @IBOutlet weak var dobLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var telephoneLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var emailLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var heightLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var weightTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var weekTextField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var neckTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var shouldersTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var chestTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var bicepTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var waistTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var hipsTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var thighTextField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        navigationItem.title = client!.name
        dobLabel.text = client!.dob
        telephoneLabel.text = client!.telephone
        emailLabel.text = client!.email
        heightLabel.text = String(describing: client!.height)
    }

    // Dismiss keyboard when empty space tapped
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        weightTextField.endEditing(true)
        weekTextField.endEditing(true)
        neckTextField.endEditing(true)
        shouldersTextField.endEditing(true)
        chestTextField.endEditing(true)
        bicepTextField.endEditing(true)
        waistTextField.endEditing(true)
        hipsTextField.endEditing(true)
        thighTextField.endEditing(true)
    }

    @IBAction func saveButton(_ sender: Any) {

        let editWeight = Double(weightTextField.text!)
        let editWeek = weekTextField.text
        let editNeck = Double(neckTextField.text!)
        let editShoulders = Double(shouldersTextField.text!)
        let editChest = Double(chestTextField.text!)
        let editBicep = Double(bicepTextField.text!)
        let editWaist = Double(waistTextField.text!)
        let editHips = Double(hipsTextField.text!)
        let editThigh = Double(thighTextField.text!)        

        do {

            let clientItem = Client(context: managedObjectContext)

            clientItem.setValue(editWeight, forKey: "oneWeekWeight")
            clientItem.setValue(editWeek, forKey: "weekOneSelected")
            clientItem.setValue(editNeck, forKey: "oneWeekNeck")
            clientItem.setValue(editShoulders, forKey: "oneWeekShoulders")
            clientItem.setValue(editChest, forKey: "oneWeekChest")
            clientItem.setValue(editBicep, forKey: "oneWeekBicep")
            clientItem.setValue(editWaist, forKey: "oneWeekWaist")
            clientItem.setValue(editHips, forKey: "oneWeekHips")
            clientItem.setValue(editThigh, forKey: "oneWeekThigh")

            try managedObjectContext.save()

            print("Data Saved Successfully")


        } catch {
            fatalError("Failed to fetch clients: \(error)")
        }

    }

}
```

Here's a screenshot of the steps I see when I run the app:

[image]

Image now edited to show correct Screenshot 4

Comment: Not sure I completely understand your question. Are you saying that you enter values for neck, shoulders, chest, etc on the 5th screen, save it, but then when you tap on Joe Bloggs on the 6th screen it segues to the last screen (WeekStatsViewController?) where the values are 0? Which images correspond to ClientListViewController and which ones correspond to WeekStatsViewController?

Comment: Hi Jim, Sorry I've just noticed the screenshot isn't accurate :( Screenshot 2 is my new client setup. when I press save it takes me back to the tableview Screenshot 3. When I click on Joe Bloggs it takes me to Joe Bloggs info Screenshot 4 which is correct at this point ignore the 0's at body measurements here. I click + to add new measurements to be saved Screenshot 5 I click save and it saves blank to my tableview below Joe Bloggs Screenshot 6 and when I press button 1 for week 1 there has been no data saved for it.  I really hope this makes sense. Sorry this is all very new to me :)

Comment: I think I do follow that - almost. So in screenshot 6, you'd see a list of Joe's saved weekly measurements if it all worked correctly or would it be a list of different clients? I'm also not sure what, "I click save and it saves blank to my tableview" really means.

Comment: Screenshot 6 is showing my error. If you look under Joe in that Screenshot you’ll see there’s a 2nd Cell created with no data in it when you click it. That screen should purely be for your client names to display as you add them. Screenshot 7 is where I should be accessing all of Joe’s weekly stat changes by clicking between the 1 & 12 at the bottom. When you click those the labels above should change to show his stats for that selected week

Comment: Okay, have you determined what `try context.fetch(Client.fetchRequest())` is returning in your `getData()` function after adding a new client name?